# Android change in view - Button state gets reset

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, view

I have a button which is basically used for start/stop. So initially the text of the button is set to start. I attached a OnClickListener to it. So whenever it gets clicked i change its text. So if it was start it become stop and vice-versa.

The problem comes when i change my phone view from portrait to landscape or vice-versa the button text gets reset.

So for example I clicked the start button---it changed to stop. Now if I tilt my phone to change the view the button text gets set to start again.

Am I using the button in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You should save your button state. When screen orientation changes, onCreate is called and all your app variables are re-intitialized. Read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you are using the button in the right way.

The thing what you are seeing is "configuration change". When you are tilting your device, Android recreating your activity and recreating all it's views (so, they getting default captions as them described in XML).

You need to do the

- disable configuration changes for your Activity. To do so, add the following to your manifest's activity tag: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. It is not suitable, if you have different layouts for landscape and portraint orientations, when you need to...
- handle the configuration changes by overriding [onSaveInsatnceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of your Activity, save a state there and then use it in [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method.

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) for further explanation

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZdceXVzG I made the changes here. I keep getting a NullPointerException. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: What line causing NPE? What is `globals` in your code? Why do you making a `putAll` call? Also, `savedInstanceState` is not always filled in (actually, on first activity start it it null), check it for null before doing a `getString` on it.